# render() must be compatible with Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\RendererInterface::render(Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)

Tags: magento2, render

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   \ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\ModuleName\Grid\Renderer\Image::render()
>   must be compatible with
>   Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\RendererInterface::render(Magento\Framework\DataObject
>   $row) in
>   C:\wamp\www\magento2\app\code\\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\ModuleName\Grid\Renderer\Image.php
>   on line 59

```
<?php
namespace <vendor-name>\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\ModuleName\Grid\Renderer;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\Object;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Image extends AbstractRenderer
{
   private $_storeManager;
   /**
    * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context
    * @param array $data
    */

   public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context, StoreManagerInterface $storemanager, array $data = [])
   {
       $this->_storeManager = $storemanager;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
       $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
       echo "test";
   }
   /**
    * Renders grid column
    *
    * @param Object $row
    * @return  string
    */
   public function render(Object $row)
   {
       $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
           \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
       );
       $imageUrl = $mediaDirectory.'/FolderPathName'.$this->_getValue($row);


       return '<img src="'.$imageUrl.'" width="50"/>';
   }
}
```

Comment: PHP expects, that the method signature is the same for a child class.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Fabian in the comment your child class method signature is different from the parent class.

The parent method from `AbstractRenderer` is

```
public function render(DataObject $row)
{
    if ($this->getColumn()->getEditable()) {
        $result = '<div class="admin__grid-control">';
        $result .= $this->getColumn()->getEditOnly() ? ''
            : '<span class="admin__grid-control-value">' . $this->_getValue($row) . '</span>';
        return $result . $this->_getInputValueElement($row) . '</div>' ;
    }
    return $this->_getValue($row);
}
```

Do you notice the difference with your method?

Your method parameters is `Object $row` where it should be `Magento\Framework\DataObject $row`.

Comment: Additional info. `Magento\Framework\Object` does not exist anymore. it was turned to `Magento\Framework\DataObject` to make Magento2 compatible with php7

Comment: I am using php 5.6 but still facing the same issue